# Statement Select * From Table Where Cursor - How To Loop This Cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, cursor

I've created a variable `IDS  TABLECLIENT.ID&type;` and i fill this var. with:

```
OPEN V_ID;
   LOOP
    FETCH V_ID INTO IDS;
    EXIT WHEN V_ID%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP; 
 CLOSE V_ID;
```

This works fine. it stores 5 id clients but when i use this in a select statement, i'm waiting 5 registers but i only get 1:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLECLIENT
 WHERE ID IN IDS;
```

Maybe i have to loop ids inside the statement? please help oracle friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IDS` - at a moment - contains only one row fetched by the cursor.

For example, this is table of departments in Scott's sample schema:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

This code simulates what you have (though, it would have been better if *you* posted that info); cursor selects department numbers and - later - uses that value in another query.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    cursor v_id is select deptno from dept;
  3    ids    dept.deptno%type;
  4    l_cnt  number;
  5  begin
  6    open v_id;
  7    loop
  8      fetch v_id into ids;
  9      exit when v_id%notfound;
 10
 11      -- display IDS's contents:
 12      dbms_output.put_line('Department ' || ids);
 13
 14      -- you can do "something" with that value; for example,
 15      -- count employees who work in that department
 16      select count(*)
 17        into l_cnt
 18        from emp
 19        where deptno = ids;
 20      dbms_output.put_line('...Number of employees in DEPT ' || ids ||
 21                           ' = ' || l_cnt);
 22    end loop;
 23    close v_id;
 24  end;
 25  /
```

Result is:

```
Department 10                           --> this is value fetched in the 1st loop round
...Number of employees in DEPT 10 = 3
Department 20                           --> fetched in the 2nd round
...Number of employees in DEPT 20 = 5
Department 30
...Number of employees in DEPT 30 = 6
Department 40
...Number of employees in DEPT 40 = 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```